# Get record key with inner join in Kafka Streams DSL

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Is there a way to pass in or get access to the message key from the `join` section in a Kafka Stream DSL join?

I have something like this right now:

```
    KStream<String, GenericRecord> completedEventsStream = inputStartKStream.
        join(
            inputEndKStream,
            (leftValue, rightValue) -> customLambda((Record) leftValue, (Record) rightValue),
            JoinWindows.of(windowDuration),
            Joined.with(stringSerde, genericAvroSerde, genericAvroSerde)
        );
```

However, the `leftValue` and `rightValue` records passed in to `customLambda` don't have access to the kafka message key, because that's a separate string.  The only content they have is the message itself, not the key.

Is there a way to get access to the key from inside the join lambda?  One thing I could do is simply add the message key as part of the message itself, and access it as a regular field there, but I was wondering if the framework provides a way to access it directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the time the key is also available in the value of the record, is this not the case for your app?

It looks like the `ValueJoiner` interface has an [improvement filed as part of KIP-149](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-149%3A+Enabling+key+access+in+ValueTransformer%2C+ValueMapper%2C+and+ValueJoiner), but hasn't been completed like the other methods in that KIP: `ValueTransformer` and `ValueMapper`.

You could add a step before your join to extract the key and include it in the value of your message before doing the join using [`ValueMapperWithKey`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/javadocs/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/ValueMapperWithKey.html).

Comment: Thanks for the link to KIP-149